# How to do Http Post with Axios (equivalence C#)

Tags: typescript, axios

I have this code in C#:

```
 HttpContent txsHttpContent =
        new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RR()
        {
            Id = id,
            Labels = new List<string>(labels),
            Ticks = 0
        }));
 txs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RR>(Client.PostAsync("list",
                                                                txsHttpContent)
                                                                .Result
                                                                .Content
                                                                .ReadAsStringAsync()
                                                                .Result);
```

Basically it's a Post with the objet HttpClient in .NET. I want to do that but in TypeScript with Axios. My current code is:

```
  const readerRequest: RR =
    {
        Id: id,
        Labels: [...labels],
        Ticks: 0
    };
const serialized = JSON.stringify(readerRequest);
let txs = axios.post(this.Configuration.BaseAddress + '/list',
                    serialized, { headers }
```

But its not working... do you have an idea?

I guess the thing is sent HttpContent or Headers because HttpContent in .NET

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you read the [example](https://axios-http.com/docs/example) on axios web site? `axios.post` returns a [promise](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp). You have to [await](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp) it or call `then` on it.